# Float formatting to 3 or 4 decimal places

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I would like to format a float to *strictly* 3 or 4 decimal places.

For example:

```
1.0     => 1.000   # 3DP  
1.02    => 1.020   # 3DP  
1.023   => 1.023   # 3DP  
1.0234  => 1.0234  # 4DP  
1.02345 => 1.0234  # 4DP
```

Kind of a combination of `'{:.5g}'.format(my_float)` and `'{:.4f}'.format(my_float)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that 1.023 isn't precisely 1.023. Which means that you can't tell from looking at the number itself whether it should have 3 or 4 decimal places.

Comment: Sorry my examples were a little simple. The behaviour needs to work for the likes of 1.0230000000001 or 1.02299999999997, which both round down to 1.0230 in 4DP, which in my case I'd like rounded down to 3DP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're asking, you can format it to 4 then drop the trailing '0' if there is one.  Like this:

```
def fmt_3or4(v):
    """Format float to 4 decimal places, or 3 if ends with 0."""
    s = '{:.4f}'.format(v)
    if s[-1] == '0':
        s = s[:-1]
    return s

>>> fmt_3or4(1.02345)
'1.0234'
>>> fmt_3or4(1.023)
'1.023'
>>> fmt_3or4(1.02)
'1.020'
```